# Does unit ball in homogeneous Riemannian manifold $M$ translates isometrically to another unit ball in $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Definition of Homogeneous Riemannian manifold: Pick a point $p \in M$. For all $q \in M$, there exists $\phi \in ISO(M)$ such that $\phi(p) = q$.

Take Riemannian metric $d$. Then, for arbitrarily small $\delta > 0$, can I assert that $B(p, \delta)$ is mapped isometrically to $B(q, \delta)$ for every $q \in M$?

Comment: Hint: the elements of the isomotry group are isomotries of metric spaces, in that for any $\phi\in\text{ISO}(M)$, $d(x,y)=d(\phi(x),\phi(y))$.